# Cannot connect to MongoHQ from Express.js code

Tags: node.js, express, mongohq

I'm new to Node and Express and am having difficulty getting data out of my database in Express.

When run from console the first code example below runs and returns data, but when I try and do the same thing from within Express it doesn't work?

Using the /scores URI I cannot get anything back from the server.  It just eventually times out.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
/**
 * Created by Mike on 2/1/14.
 */
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var connectionUri = "mongodb://app_user:xxxxxxx@troup.mongohq.com:10000/??????'";
var mongodb = require('mongodb'), MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
MongoClient.connect(connectionUri, function (err, db) {
    if (err) throw error;

    var collection = db.collection('sessions');

    collection.findOne({}, function (err, doc) {
        if (err) throw err;

        console.log(doc.results);

        db.close();
    });
});
```

Here is the app.js Express code:

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var express = require('express');
var routes = require('./routes');
var user = require('./routes/user');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
var mongo = require('mongodb');

var app = express();

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

app.get('/api', function(request, response) {
    response.send({name:"Raymond",age:40});
});
app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/users', user.list);
app.get('/scores', routes.scores);
app.get('/sessions', routes.sessions);
//app.post('/session', routes.session(db));

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

And finally here is the routes/index.js file.  (The connection string has been cleaned up)

```
/*
 * GET home page.
 */

exports.index = function (req, res) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
};

exports.sessions = function (req,res) {
    "use strict";
    res.render('index', { title: 'Scores' });
};

exports.scores = function (db) {
    return function (req, res) {
        "use strict";
        var connectionUri = "mongodb://app_user:xxxxxxxxx@troup.mongohq.com:00000/??????";
        var mongodb = require('mongodb'), MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
        MongoClient.connect(connectionUri, function (err, db) {
            if (err) throw error;

            var collection = db.collection('sessions');

            collection.findOne({}, function (err, doc) {
                if (err) throw err;

                res.render('scores', {
                    "scores": doc
                });

                db.close();
            });
        });
        /*var collection = db.get('sessions');
        collection.find({}, {}, function (e, docs) {
            res.render('scores', {
                "scores" : docs
            });
        });*/
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the function you are exporting for `exports.scores` is expecting the `db` object to be passed in.

`exports.scores = function (db) {`

Your `app.js` is just using that as the route handler and is passing `req` and `res` into it while it is expecting the `db` object. When the route gets hit all you are doing is returning a function.

For this to work you'll need to export the function you are currently returning.

`exports.scores = function (req, res) {`

**Please Note!!!**

You are creating a connection **every** time a request comes through that route. While you do close it at the end if the route becomes busy you are opening many pools of connections to your database unnecessarily. It is better to open a connection at a central point and then pass around the `db` object from there.